# Project Euler number 8

Tags: javascript

They asked me to learn JavaScript for work, so I'm doing some of the solutions on Project Euler to help me learn.

My solution for [problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) works for the 4 number example they give, if I change the 13s to 4s, but it doesn't get the right answer for 13 digits as the question wants.

I solved this problem forever ago in C and don't remember it giving me this much trouble.  Am I doing something wrong with JavaScript or is this a error with my code?  In either case, please point me in the right direction.

My code:

```
var numbas = "\
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

var biggestProduct = 0;
var currentProduct = 0;
var currentNumbas = {};

function product (proddedNumbas){
    var productHolda = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        productHolda *= proddedNumbas[i];
    return productHolda;
}

for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
    for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        currentNumbas[i] = numbas[j+i];
        currentProduct = product(currentNumbas);
        if (currentProduct > biggestProduct)
            biggestProduct = currentProduct;
    }

console.log(biggestProduct);
```

Comment: What's the expected solution?

Comment: I don't know.  The website doesn't tell until after you get it.

Comment: do you actually name your variables like that, or did you refactor just for laughs :D

Comment: I named them like that for my own laughs.  I am quite bored at the moment :)

Comment: @Evert: don't create that tag please, it was [burninated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275935/burninate-project-euler) for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should be

```
for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        currentNumbas[i] = numbas[j+i];
        currentProduct = product(currentNumbas);
    }
    if (currentProduct > biggestProduct)
        biggestProduct = currentProduct;
}
```

You just needed to move the `if` clause outside of the inner loop; this compares the product after it is complete.

This gives the expected answer 23514624000.